# Search MySQL JSON field on any index

Tags: mysql, json

I have a specific json structure

```
{ 
   "id:":"123456",
   "elements":[ 
      { 
         "name":"test1",
         "txt":"random1"
      },
      { 
         "name":"test2",
         "txt":"random2"
      },
      { 
         "name":"test3",
         "tx3":"random3"
      },

      etc...
   ]
}
```

This is my current query that checks only on specific index:

```
select column->>'$.id' as m FROM table WHERE column->>'$.elements[0].name' = 'test1'
```

I would like to check whether any of the elements has the name i am looking for. Something like `elements[*].name = 'test1'`

Additional:
Is there an option to return all elements text, where element has specific name?

For example:

```
select <elements:txt> where <elements:name> = 'test1'
```

Comment: This is why it's a bad idea to use the JSON datatype.

Comment: @Barmar ... at least on MySQL.  On Postgres, the JSON API is much more robust, and can be quite useful ^ ^

Comment: Why is `elements` an object instead of an array?

Comment: @Barmar typo, example written by hand :) I know it is bad idea, but it is a existing database i have to search on :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`JSON_SEARCH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search), checking to see if it returns `NULL` (no match) when looking for the string in each of the element names:

```
SELECT column->>'$.id' AS m 
FROM table
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(column, 'one', 'test1', NULL, '$.elements.*.name') IS NOT NULL
```

If elements is actually an array, you would change the query to:

```
SELECT column->>'$.id' AS m 
FROM table
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(column, 'one', 'test1', NULL, '$.elements[*].name') IS NOT NULL
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=811b21f835ea59a3991cf5cf35abf03d)

To extract the matching `txt` value requires hacking the path returned from `JSON_SEARCH`, replacing the `.name` part with `.txt` and then passing that to `JSON_EXTRACT`:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(j, REPLACE(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(j, 'one', 'test2', NULL, '$.elements[*].name')), '.name', '.txt')) AS txt
FROM test
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(j, 'one', 'test2', NULL, '$.elements[*].name') IS NOT NULL
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=52c1dd11b8e23be7f80f47341821e2fe)